# Why isn't Octave reading in the entire 14 bits of my .NEF raw files?

Tags: image-processing, octave, bit-depth, dcraw

I am using a Nikon D5200. I intend to do some image processing on the raw images shot with the camera. But I am encountering a problem when I read the raw images using GNU Octave. Rather than giving bit depth of 16 (since the .NEF are shot at 14-bit depth), the result is just a 8-bit array. What might be the problem?

> imfinfo("/media/karthikeyan/3434-3531/DCIM/100D5200/DSC_1094.NEF")
>
> ans =
>
> scalar structure containing the fields:
>
> Filename = /media/karthikeyan/3434-3531/DCIM/100D5200/DSC_1094.NEF
>
> FileModDate = 10-Oct-2016 18:10:02
>
> FileSize = 26735420
>
> Format = DCRAW
>
> FormatVersion =
>
> Width = 6036
>
> Height = 4020
>
> BitDepth = 8
>
> ColorType = truecolor

The result from `exiftool` is as follows:

> exiftool DSC_1094.NEF | grep -i bit
>
> Bits Per Sample : 14

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, Octave 4.0.3.

Comment: The first time you use `imread`, `imfinfo`, or `imread`, do you get a warning similar to "your version of GraphicsMagick limits images to 8 bits per pixel"?

Comment: @carandraug No I rebuilt Graphics Magick with  quantum-depth 16 bit. Read  a .TIFF which is 16-bit depth and `imfinfo` yields right result. .NEF  does not  seem to.

Comment: well, Octave relies on GraphicsMagick to read the images. I guess it is possible that GraphicsMagick NEF reader still only reads 8 bit. Try `gm identify -verbose DSC_1094.NEF` and check. Then report a bug with Octave if `gm identify` reports the right info, or with GraphicsMagick otherwise.